# Django CSRF missing or Sessions middleware required

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

When trying to create a django(2) rest framework api, I keep getting this error.

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /login/
```

After doing some research the problem might be with sessions authentication which I don't really need since I will be replying on token based auth. When I try to remove some of the session auth from my settings I end up getting this.

```
AssertionError: The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE setting to insert 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'.
```

Settings.py snippet

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # API (v1)
    'apiV1.v1.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Requirements
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'apiV1.urls'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from apiV1.v1.accounts.models.user import User
from apiV1.v1.accounts.serializers.user import UserSerializerLogin


# login
class LoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        """
        Get user data and API token
        """

        user = get_object_or_404(User, email=request.data.get('email'))
        user = authenticate(username=user.email, password=request.data.get('password'))
        if user:
            serializer = UserSerializerLogin(user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: show your template. do you have  `{% csrf_token %}` inside your `login` form?

Comment: i am strickly making an api call to it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the comment from SessionMiddleware inside your settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need session for authentication you have to use token authentication.

Here is the example of view

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Login(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        ---
        serializer: AuthTokenSerializer
        """

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        return Response({
            'pk': user.pk,
            'first_name': user.first_name,
            'last_name': user.last_name,
        })
```

Or you can use `JWT` authentication.

Here are some helpful links for you.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error as I was checking something on stackoverflow.It can be used for future references.Firts of all I like the way sessions are structured inside the classes are well structured inside the MIDDLEWARE section.
The problem with the code is that inside the MIDDLEWARE class the

```
# 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
```

is commented out.Uncomment the above line of code.
In django when a user logs in a session is cerated using the above mentioned session.This works that way if one is using session based authentification in your project.
To learn more about sessions in Django kindly refer to this documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/sessions/